# Apache Ignite Locks for synchronizing arbitrary computation across the grid

Tags: api, ignite, locks

I have a simple question for which I can't really find a definitive answer in the Apache Ignite docs.

I see that there is an API in Apache Ignite to create a explicit lock. I understand that these locks are used for writing cache entries and this is done implicitly.

However, can I (should I) be able to explicitly create a Lock in my grid to synchronizing computation some arbitrary code. Here's what I'm thinking of doing:

1. Request comes into my API.
2. I try to enter a lock on my Ignite cache
3. If I can enter the lock I do some calculation (which should only be done on one of my API instances at any given time)
4. If I can't enter the lock, I return 409 error code (duplicate request)
5. I exit the lock

Are there potential caveats to doing this? Should I watch out for potential pitfalls?

Comment: Do you want to create a separate lock for each computation? Or after one computation finishes, another is allowed to be executed on the same lock?

Comment: One lock per request. Each request has lets say 5 fields that are concatenated together into a lock cache key. But once the critical section is finished and the lock exits, it's not reused again. I keep a reference to the cache itself, so I don't have to re-created/ retrieve it on every request.

Comment: Sounds like you can achieve this with a cluster singleton: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-singletons

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use cache locks for entering critical section in a distributed manner. Here you can find how: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-locks

Here you can find some more documentation on Ignite locks: https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/pe/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteLock.html

Ignite cache locks implement mutual exclusion, so you can rely on that no two threads or processes are holding one lock at the same time. You should only make sure that nodes use replicas of the same cache to acquire locks (cache is not local, etc) and your cache is transactional.

Usually locks are used to perform complex operations on the cache atomically. If you want to use locking without actually changing the cache, it may be a symptom of that you don't actually need this lock, or you should use some synchronization mechanism of a resource you are trying to utilize inside of the critical section. It depends on the computations you are trying to perform.